# Mongo Aggregation, replacing array inside results in array with count of that inner array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, projection

I'm working on a social network kind of schema and trying to use the aggregation framework to alter the documents during the pipeline to summarize parts of it, specificially, to replace arrays of data with the size of the array.

For example, given these **original documents**, each of which holds an array of posts, each post has an array of likes:

```
{ "_id": 1, "posts": [
  {
    "content": "foobar", "likes": [ "11", "12", "13" ]
  }
] }
{ "_id": 2, "posts": [
  {
  "content": "foobar2", "likes": [ "22", "23" ]
  }
] }
{ "_id": 3, "posts": [
  {
  "content": "foobar3", "likes": [ "33" ]
  }
] }
```

(that can be fed straight into `mongoimport`)

In the real world there would be many elements in the `posts` arrays, and more complicated elements in the `likes` arrays.  I need to **return documents with a count of the likes**, instead of the actual likes themselves, e.g.

```
{ _id: 1, posts: [
  { content: 'foobar', likeCount: 3 }
] },
{ _id: 2, posts: [
  { content: 'foobar2', likeCount: 2 }
] },
{ _id: 3, posts: [
  { content: 'foobar3', likeCount: 1 }
] }
```

The `$project` aggregation stage seems suitable but I cannot get it to product required results.  e.g.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "posts.likeCount": { $size: "$posts.likes" }
        }
    }
])
```

Gives:

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "posts" : [ 
        {
            "likeCount" : 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "posts" : [ 
        {
            "likeCount" : 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "posts" : [ 
        {
            "likeCount" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

The `$posts.likes` usage in the `$project` expression seems especially off, since `$posts` is an array.

How can my output documents contain an aggregation (count) of this inner array, while still maintaining the structure of the original documents?

I tried `$unwind` and `$replaceRoot` stages to try to work toward a solution but ended up with less specific structures that lose the surrounding fields from the originals.  I've been reading the MongoDB ref docs, and searching SO and elsewhere, but haven't dug up a solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query. `$map` to iterate the `posts` array and use `$size` to calculate the count of `likes`.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "posts": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$posts",
        "as": "post",
        "in": {
          "content": "$$post.content",
          "likeCount": {
            "$size": "$$post.likes"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to count likes per content, you need to unwind posts first:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$posts"}, 
    {$project: {
        "posts.content" : 1,
        "posts.likeCount": { $size: "$posts.likes" }
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: "$_id", 
        posts: {$push: "$posts"}
    }}
])
```

Comment: This looks correct, as with Veeram's answer below.  See results gist at https://gist.github.com/neekfenwick/dd97b7c3e6b9f1da46828941b6213275 where I added more documents for better verification.  Now I am not sure what answer to accept :) Suggestions?

Comment: noscript just deleted the other Answer by him so my links to my gists in my comments have disappeared :) re: https://gist.github.com/neekfenwick/98d6ad47cc9f15ea685a8d0ab9413c59 @Veeram, if you were to post your answer again I'd happy upvote it, but am still unsure which of yours or Alex's is more 'correct'.  His has more pipeline stages so I presume is less efficient.  I have a test framework here with 10000*100 objects I can test later but I have to run right now.

Comment: @Veeram s one has better performance